# Problema com versão do PHP e wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando aprender wordpress e me deparei com o seguinte problema: tenho dois notebooks com Windows 7 e no mais antigo a versão mais atual do wordpress deu incompatibilidade com o PHP versão 5.5.12, no notebook mais novo também com windows 7 deu outra msg de erro devido o PHP estar muito atual  (7.3.10)  exibindo o erro:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoWP\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1072 .

Fiz algumas pesquisas, apliquei a solução sugerido mas sem êxito.

A questão é a seguinte: se eu atualizar o wamp irá automaticamente atualizar o php e o mysql, isso irá subscrever a instalação anterior? Irei perder os BDs existentes no mysql?

Táa uma zica isso, nunca vi isso, em um note tá antiga demais e no outro está atual demais, vai entender...

Answer (score -3):

Se você não quer desinstalar, você pode usar um outro servidor local como o xamp. De qualquer forma para não perder os bancos, faça backup. De todo modo, o problema não é a versão do windows e sim a versão do seu wamp, que em uma máquina está desatualizado.

Comment: Desinstalei o xampp e instalei o wamp mais atual, porém deu msg que falta uma dll. A coisa ta tão esquisita que vou tentar um terceiro computador.

Comment: O mais incrível é que nem em fóruns em inglês eu encontrei a solução pra o erro apontado inicialmente.

Comment: O wamp não é atualizado há algum tempo, e volte e meia dá algum erro de DLL.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, fiz uma alteração na linha 1072 alterando cont para in_array, e problema foi solucionado.